# How to do an if statement from the result of an executed command

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, netstat

I am trying to do an IF statement from the output of an executed commmand.  Here is how I am trying to do it, but it doesn't work.   Does anyone know the right way to do this?

```
if [ "`netstat -lnp | grep ':8080'`" == *java* ]; then
  echo "Found a Tomcat!"
fi
```

EDIT:
I wonder if there is a way to do it by capturing exit code?

Comment: Regarding your recent edit: You _are_ capturing the exit code, of the `[` utility.  The currently accepted answer captures the exit code of `[[`, and the other answer captures the exit code of the `grep -q` pipeline.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Use the bash `[[` conditional construct and prefer the `$(`<command>`)` command substitution convention. Additionally, `[[` prevents word splitting of variable values therefore there is no need to quote the command substitution bit..

```
if [[ $(netstat -lnp | grep ':8080') == *java* ]]; then
  echo "Found a Tomcat!"
fi
```

Comment: `Additionally, [[ prevents word splitting of variable values therefore there is no need to quote the command substitution bit` Can you elaborate on this concept? I don't see any variables in here: what would an example look like where this made a difference?

Answer (score 52):

Another alternative is to simply test the exit status of `grep` itself, which will return false (non-zero) if there was no match and true (zero) if there was one, by not using the `[` command.

```
if netstat -lntp | grep -q ':8080.*java'; then
    echo "Found a Tomcat!"
fi
```

Comment: Newb here: is this "idiomatic" bash or is it "clever code"?

Answer (score 10):

Even more simple,

```
netstat -lntp | grep ':8080.*java' > /dev/null && command
```

If you just want to do one thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can do more precise, yet simple, matching with awk.

```
if netstat -lnp | awk '$4 ~ /:8080$/ && $7 ~ /java/ {exit(0)} END {exit(1)}'; then …
```

To match the structure of your command more closely, the portable way of doing wildcard matching on a string in a shell is with the `case` construct.

```
case "$(netstat -lnp | grep ':8080')" in
  *java*)  echo "Found a Tomcat!";;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it in a script that determines whether my music player is open or not, and if a song is playing if it is open.

```
rbstatus=$(rhythmbox-client --print-playing)

pgrep -x rhythmbox >/dev/null && if [ "$rbstatus" = "-" ]; then
   echo "No music playing"
else
   rhythmbox-client --print-playing
fi || echo "Music player is Closed."
```

Comment: Welcome on U&L! A side note: consider that [`&&`/`||` is not equivalent to `if`/`else`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335832/315749). Your code will print "Music player is Closed." even if `pgrep` succeeds and the command in the `else` block fails (returns a non-zero status) for some reason (likely not a real issue in your case, of course).

Comment: Nice alternative way of doing it.   :-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple and logic way:

```
netcat -zw3 localhost 8000 && echo 'tomcat is up'
```